# background en evento focus en tag <a> html

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un tipo panel de iconos donde el usuario puede seleccionar un icono, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario seleccione el icono este se ilumine (esto lo hace solo cuando paso el mouse por encima del icono pero no permanece iluminado cuando lo selecciono y es lo que requiero) y el background del icono cambie de color, pero resulta que ya cambia de color el background del icono pero en lugar de circulo he logrado hacer un rectangulo con las esquinas redondeadas, en la imagen se puede ver que el icono de color amarillo es cuando ya he dado clic en ese icono y el icono de color azul es cuando paso por encima del icono el mouse, como se habran dado cuenta el icono de color amarillo no se forma todo el circulo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.list-unstyled {
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;

}
.list-inline li {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 
.social-icons .fa {
font-size: 1em;
}

.social-icons .fa {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-icons.icon-circle .fa{
border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-icons.icon-rounded .fa{
border-radius:5px;
}
.social-icons.icon-flat .fa{
border-radius: 0;
}
.social-icons .fa:hover, .social-icons .fa:active {
    background-color:blue;
color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
}
.social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:hover, .social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:active {

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}
.social-icons.icon-rotate .fa:hover, .social-icons.icon-rotate .fa:active {

-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
}

.enlace > a:focus {
 cursor:pointer;
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:30%;
}
```

```html
 <ul id="navegador" class="social-icons icon-circle list-unstyled list-inline">
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-css3"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linux"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trello"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias explicar mejor cual es el problema? , no logro entender. Solo quieres cambiar el color en el onfocus del icono?

Comment: @FacundoFernandez 1. No logro hacer el background amarillo en forma de circulo como el de color azull y 2. iluminar el icono a color mas blanco cuando haya dado clic en el icono ya que como comento solo funciona caundo paso por encima e mouse

Comment: Bueno ya encontre el problema, antes una pregunta, fuiste vos el que hiciste el css?

Comment: @FacundoFernandez No, solo he querido darle los estilos que me han gustado de un ejemplo que encontré navegando en internet a mi ejercicio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno Ivxn, el problema viene es esta clase

```
.enlace > a:focus {
 cursor:pointer;
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:30%;
}
```

Tendrias que aplicarlo en .fa no en el link(a), por ejemplo:

```
.enlace > a:focus .fa {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Tambien tenias mal el border-radius, tiene que ser 50%

Despues tambien tiene esta clase:

```
.social-icons .fa {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Repites dos veces la propiedad color

```
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
```

Y queda seteada el color blanco con una transparencia. Elimina la segunda linea linea.

Te dejo un ejemplo, espero que haya sido de utilidad, saludos.

```css
body{
  background:gray;
}

.list-unstyled {
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;

}
.list-inline li {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 
/*Cambio el tamaño de letra o fuente*/
.social-icons .fa {
font-size: 1em;
}
/*Change icons circle size and color here*/
.social-icons .fa {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;

-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-icons.icon-circle .fa{
border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-icons.icon-rounded .fa{
border-radius:5px;
}
.social-icons.icon-flat .fa{
border-radius: 0;
}
.social-icons .fa:hover, 
.social-icons .fa:active {
    background-color:blue;
color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333;
}
.social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:hover, 
.social-icons.icon-zoom .fa:active {

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}
.social-icons.icon-rotate .fa:hover, 
.social-icons.icon-rotate .fa:active {

-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
transform: scale(1.1) rotate(360deg);
}

.enlace > a:focus .fa {
 cursor:pointer;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8df9df0ff7.js"></script>

<ul id="navegador" class="social-icons icon-circle list-unstyled list-inline">
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-android"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-css3"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linux"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trello"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: que amable gracias!